# When MediaPlayerElement playing m3u8, sound always comes faster than video frame

Tags: uwp, media-player

I'm using `MediaPlayerElement`, when playing m3u8, sound always comes faster than video frame.

Test [repo](https://github.com/hupo376787/MediaElementSoundBug.git), or a public m3u8 url searched on google: https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8

Is anything we can do to avoid this bug???

Comment: Hi, I can't reproduce your question. Have you tried updating the system decoder or running the application on another machine with a higher configuration? May be related to this.

Comment: My cpu is i7, memory 16GB. Maybe you can try on a slow network. My network is 100MB. Btw, my winver is 18362.295.

Comment: Hi, I tested the video with multiple devices and it works fine. This may not be a problem with `MediaPlayerElement`. You can try to test the video with other players. If the audio and video are not synchronized, please update the graphics driver or try to set the headset/horn to the default playback device in the sound settings.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I'll try.